# Django+fastcgi+nginx logging

Tags: django, windows, nginx

I was given django project from another developer. It based on windows server(Django+fastcgi+nginx). 
In settings.py present option DEBUG=True but the anyone of the errorlog-files does not contain debugging information
**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/error.log;
error_log  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/error.log  info;
error_log  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/error.log  error;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        client_max_body_size    32m;
        error_log    C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/db-rlocalhost.error_log;
        error_log    C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/db-rlocalhost.error_log notice;
        error_log    C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/db-rlocalhost.error_log info;
        error_log    C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/nginx/logs/db-rlocalhost.error_log error;

        location / {    
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization; 
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Accel-Redirect;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Sendfile;
            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors    off;
            fastcgi_param       CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
            fastcgi_param       CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
            fastcgi_param       PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param       QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
            fastcgi_param       REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param       REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
            fastcgi_param       REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param       SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
            fastcgi_param       SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
            fastcgi_param       SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        }
        location /media/  {
            alias H:/AUCTION/;
        }
        location  /static/ {
            alias  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/static/;
        }
        location  /static_ac_invoice/ {
            alias  C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/tender/ac_invoice/static/;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

**Running server**:

```
c:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\Scripts\python.exe c:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\tender\manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8888
C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\nginx\nginx.exe
```

How can I get debug info without reconfigure project for running in non fastcgi mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8888 daemonize=false
```

Now I can see debug info.

Why is key daemonize=false not present in help output manage.py?

Comment: it wouldn't be, because that's a flag for `runfcgi`, as in the [`1.8 docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#examples)

Comment: project is using 1.7 :(

Comment: Still applicable